# Converting a seq to vector clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

```
 (defn coord-pairs [coords]
   (for [number2 coords]
        (for [number coords]
         (vector (get coords number2) number)))
  )
```

Output:

```
(([0 0] [0 1]) ([1 0] [1 1]))
```

I want the output to be like

```
[[0 0] [0 1] [1 0] [1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queue this to your output

```
#(mapv vec (partition 2 (flatten %)))
```

or

```
#(vec (apply concat %))
```

I'm not too sure about the intent of your code but...

```
(fn [coords] (vec (for [x coords y coords] [(get coords x) y])))
```